# Why Typescript is not throwing error when an empty array value is assigned to a type of array of non empty objects?

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects

```
let obj: {
    id_1: number;
    id_2: number;
}[] = [];
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BTCUAIF4D5wbwFDmQGwKYBdwHsBGArALniWWQEsATAfQEZiA7AVwFtc0AnAblLKuoBMjVu269wAXwDaAXSjhZPcQGNsDAM7Z0AOhTYA5sDz5QPZBNBgz4IA)

## 2 Questions

### 1)How do I define types if I don't want to allow empty array value?

Array should contain object or objects with both the defined keys id_1 and id_2, but cannot be empty

### 2)How is this valid typescript and why does the TS compiler not throwing errors when an empty array is passed to a array of object type?

---

I am new to TS and cannot understand the above behaviour, someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a specific Type to make an "unemptyable" array. [Ref here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-non-empty-array)

Eg : [Ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BTCUAIF4D5wbwFDnAFwJ4AcCm4ByB7AOwFEBbDdAQQCdqBDNAFSwGcUAeR2ScAbUYA04AHSjGvALoSA3EmQAbLCnD4ARgCsAXHiJkKaGvSasOiZOYCWAEwD6ARm2EArqVVZqs88ms2ATI5c3DzlkAF9uPhkEEPAAYyIWfEVheXwAc2A1dVBPcFDQMFygA)

EDIT : eg if the playground is not working

```
type NonEmptyArrayTest<T> = [T, ...T[]];
let obj: NonEmptyArrayTest<{
  id_1: number;
  id_2: number;
}>;
```

Comment: You should include the code in the answer itself in case the links stop working in the future